# Visual studio online source control breaks debugging

Tags: version-control, visual-studio, tfs

I'm completely new to source/version control and I recently decided to try out the Visual Studio online service (the renamed TFS online service). I ran into a problem and now I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or is the VSOnline service faulty.

Problem is as follows:
Completely working Windows phone 8 project. Compiler and debugger working as expected in VS13 ultimate (also in VS12 pro).
However, when I add the project to source control and check it in. Then check it back out it  breaks.

Symptoms: 
1) XAML markup not recognized. IntelliSense reports error for every single XAML tag, even fundamental tags like Phone:PhoneApplicationPage. These errors can be cleared if I change from debug to release mode, but they re-appear when I launch project next time.

2) Debug target not changeable. In the dialog where you can typically choose between device and different emulator modes there is only one option "start". Impossible to deploy app on actual device. "Start" always launches default emulator (which works fine, no bugs there), but you can't choose which emulator.

3) VS13 crashes when I try to open debug tab in project properties/settings.

4) Attempt to build the solution in VSonline fails.

I realize there is a possibility I'm doing something wrong. Never used source control before, but in my understanding I still should be able to handle the project completely normal after check-out. Restrictions to debugging or deploying to device would seem counter-productive to me.

And also the false errors and VS13 crashing in settings implies there is something broken.
Any opinion, advice or help will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I use VS 2013 with TFS online for all my source control across dozens of projects and it works well. I have not used it with a Windows 8 phone project, so I can't vouch for that. Ultimately (while it very well could be a bug in VS 2013), there isn't anything inherent to source control or cloud-based source control that should restrict you from these basic tasks. In other words, don't give up on good source control practices just because of this. Usually it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of relentless effort I was able to solve the problem.

As I work from home and my own computer, I'm always logged in with my personal account.
And I was logged in visual studio with my work account which has the MSDN subscription.

This caused account clash and all the odd behavior. Logging out from all browser didn't help, it mysteriously kept my personal account always logged in. And I believe this is caused by Skydrive.

So I set up new user account for my work id, log in using that and all started working perfectly.

Bottom line: If you wish to use visual studio online or log in in VS, make sure you are logged in with same account on the computer.